# call JS function inside razor foreach statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `Model` with `LevelInfo` property:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string>> LevelInfo { get; set; }
```

In the view I have a JS function:

```
function fillPath(level, color) {
        $('[level=' + level).attr({ 'fill': color });
    }
```

Now I want to iterate through `LevelInfo`  and call `fillPath` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        @foreach (var info in Model.LevelInfo)
        {
            // How can I call JS function from here?
            // i.e,  fillPath(info.Item1, info.Item2)
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to call `fillPath` on the server or the client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember, the `@foreach` is executed server-side and emits HTML for things between `{` and `}`.

Simply write JavaScript right between the brackets.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    @foreach (var info in Model.LevelInfo)
    {
        fillPath(info.Item1, info.Item2) // Assumes this is a function defined in JavaScript elsewhere
    }
});
```

Razor is sometimes a bit picky about recognizing a transition from server-side to client-side code.  You may need to wrap the JavaScript code in `<text>` to help Razor along.